# Criando pasta que não apaga ao desinstalar para salvar backup - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de backup usando path_provider, com o seguinte código.

```
  // Busca o local que esta o arquivo
  Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'base.db');
  File sourceFile = File(path);
  List<int> content = await sourceFile.readAsBytes();

  // Define diretório que o arquivo de backup será salvo
  final targetDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  final targetDirFolder = Directory('${targetDir.path}/Backup/');

  final targetPath = join(targetDir.path, 'backup-driive.db');
  File targetFile = File(targetPath);
  await targetFile.writeAsBytes(content, flush: true);
```

Com esse código consigo salvar o backup nesta pasta: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.app.combustivel/files/arquivodebackup.db", porem quando o aplicativo é desinstalado essa pasta é removida e não serve de nada o "backup", de qual forma posso salvar esse arquivo na pasta do armazenamento interno do celular onde não é apagado, andei pesquisando porem não achei nada.

Comment: Você tem que mudar a pasta onde está salvando o backup, quando o app é desinstalado o android remove a pasta br.com.app.combustivel e tudo que estiver nela. Outra alternativa seria configurar o auto backup, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

Answer (score 1):

**Você pode salvar na pastar Downloads do Android**. Veja abaixo como salvar um arquivo nessa pasta. Lembrar que essa pasta é livre, o usuário terá acesso e poderá apagar o backup. Você poderá nomear o arquivo com o nome do seu app e data do backup.

Veja no [link original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995621/how-to-download-a-file-and-store-it-in-downloads-folder-using-flutter)

Dependências

```
dio: ^3.0.0
path_provider: ^1.3.0
simple_permissions: ^0.1.9
file_utils: ^0.1.3
```

Permissões

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Código

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';
import 'package:file_utils/file_utils.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(Downloader());

 class Downloader extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
       title: "File Downloader",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FileDownloader(),
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
     );
 }

class FileDownloader extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FileDownloaderState createState() => _FileDownloaderState();
}

class _FileDownloaderState extends State<FileDownloader> {

final imgUrl = "https://images6.alphacoders.com/683/thumb-1920-683023.jpg";
bool downloading = false;
var progress = "";
var path = "No Data";
var platformVersion = "Unknown";
Permission permission1 = Permission.WriteExternalStorage;
var _onPressed;
static final Random random = Random();
Directory externalDir;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  downloadFile();
}


Future<void> downloadFile() async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  bool checkPermission1 =
      await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
  // print(checkPermission1);
  if (checkPermission1 == false) {
    await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permission1);
    checkPermission1 = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
  }
  if (checkPermission1 == true) {
    String dirloc = "";
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      dirloc = "/sdcard/download/";
    } else {
      dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    }

    var randid = random.nextInt(10000);

    try {
      FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
      await dio.download(imgUrl, dirloc + randid.toString() + ".jpg",
          onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
        setState(() {
          downloading = true;
          progress =
              ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      downloading = false;
      progress = "Download Completed.";
      path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".jpg";
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      progress = "Permission Denied!";
      _onPressed = () {
        downloadFile();
      };
    });
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('File Downloader'),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: downloading
            ? Container(
                height: 120.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Downloading File: $progress',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(path),
                  MaterialButton(
                    child: Text('Request Permission Again.'),
                    onPressed: _onPressed,
                    disabledColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    height: 40.0,
                    minWidth: 100.0,
                  ),
                ],
              )));
  }
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você salva os dados através do `Dio`, que faz um download de um aquivo, mas no caso da pergunta, é um arquivo local que ele quer fazer backup, ele não vai conseguir usar o `Dio`. E outra, você setou fixo o caminho `"/sdcard/download/"` nem sempre o usuário vai ter um _sdCard_...

Comment: A resposta seria para salvar na pasta downloads como opção para que o backup não seja removido. Ele pode usar o `"plugin ext_storage 1.0.3"` e a achar a pasta do downloads.
`ExtStorage.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Comment: Entendi, seria interessante então você ter citado tal package em sua resposta também... Mas é um bom exemplo para ele seguir!

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou utilizar o comando `getLibraryDirectory()`?

De acordo com o que está descrito no fonte do package, esse comando retorna um diretório que serve para armazenar dados persistentes e para backups, sendo que também é invisível para o usuário.

> ```
> /// Path to the directory where application can store files that are persistent,
> /// backed up, and not visible to the user, such as sqlite.db.
> ///
> /// On Android, this function throws an [UnsupportedError] as no equivalent
> /// path exists.
> Future<Directory> getLibraryDirectory() async {
>   final String path = await _platform.getLibraryPath();
>   if (path == null) {
>     return null;
>   }
>   return Directory(path);
> }
> ```

Comment: Vou tentar daqui a polco atualizo aqui

Comment: Acabei me esquecendo de atualizar, mas essa solução no android lança um erro, de acordo com a documentação só funciona em dispositivos IOS.